# Ajax call TYPO3 Controller function

Tags: jquery, ajax, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

how can I use ajax in Typo3 Backend to call a controller function of my own extension?

I want to do a search over my repository.

For example:

I have an Input field where I can enter a Name. Then the search function should search in my repository for this name.

My problem is how to set the ajax call to communicate with the controller function?

Comment: With which part have you problem exactly ?

Comment: how the url should look like

`$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In backend module that's pretty simple, just register new action in your controller, i.e: `nameAutocomplete` (don't forget to add this into your list of allowed actions in ext_tables.php)

so you can create proper url with ViewHelper:

```
<script>
    var MY_AJAX_ACTION_URL = '<f:uri.action action="nameAutocomplete" />';

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: MY_AJAX_ACTION_URL
    });

</script>
```

The sample action is quite straight i.e. if you need JSON output, you can do it directly:

```
public function nameAutocompleteAction() {
    $out = array('status' => 'I am alive');

    // Process your POSt data here

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    return json_encode($out);
}
```

Note: you need to use viewhelper to build proper URL as it creates i.e. module's token and other specific parts.

Comment: Yeah that works fine but can't read my post data.

i do this: `jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: MY_AJAX_ACTION_URL,
                    data: "nextInterval"
                });` but I cant get the data in Backend. I tried this: `$this->request->hasArgument('nextInterval')`